# How to count the number of instances of a particular subsequence

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a file that has long string; what i could not do is search and count 
a particular subsequence. I want to count the number of "ABD" substring in veryLongWord.txt file. The below is what i have currently.

```
<?php

      $file = fopen("veryLongWord.txt", "r");

      /*
      inside veryLongWord.txt
      ABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABDABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABDABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABDABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABDABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABD
      ABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABDABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABDABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABDABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABDABDBBAABAADBBADABDADDAABBABD    
      */

      $word = "";
      while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        $word .= trim($line);
      }
      fclose($file);

      $subseq = null;

      $count = 0;



      print $subseq . " shows " . $count . " times <br/>";

    ?>
```

Comment: Please tell us what attempts you've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a function to do that: [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
$contentsOfVeryLongWord = file_get_contents("veryLongWord.txt");
$count = substr_count($contentsOfVeryLongWord, 'ABD');
```

Comment: what else you need to do?